# Upload an image to firebase and display as an asset

Tags: flutter

This is the code I think will help upload and store the image to firebase

```
Future getImage() async {
    var pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("post");
    StorageTaskSnapshot snapshot =
        await ref.putFile(File(_image.path)).onComplete;

    setState(() {
      _image = PickedFile(pickedFile.path);
    });

    return await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
  }
```

This is the code that helps to select the image

```
InkWell(
        onTap: getImage,
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: (_image != null)
              ? Image.file(File(_image.path))
              : enter code hereIcon(
                  Icons.add_a_photo,
                  color: Colors.purple,
                  size: 50,
                ),
        ),
      ),
```

The are my packages

```
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.7
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+4
  firebase_storage: ^3.1.6
  firebase_database: ^3.1.1
```

My concern is, I want a user to upload an image and it will appear as a post.

Answer (score 0):

you cant get the image directly from firestore, you can only get the downloadUrl and upload it to cloud firebase and get the URL from the database and use it in `Image.Network() or NetWorkImage()`

```
String image;
File _image;
final picker = ImagePicker();

Future getImage() async {
final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: 
ImageSource.gallery);

setState(() {
  _image = PickedFile(pickedFile.path);
});
```

}

```
Future uloadPic()async{
    StorageReference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("post");
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_image);
     StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
       final String url = (await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL());
      setState(() {
  image = url
}); }
```

Now upload the String to firestore and retrieve it and use it in your networkimage